# Tabs of equal width in TabControl

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have 4 tabs at the top of a tab control. I would like for each tab to use 25% of the TabControl's width.

What is the correct way, using XAML, to do that?

Here is what I have tried:

```
<Grid  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="458" Margin="10,65,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="276">
    <TabControl Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <TabItem Header="Cameras">
            <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="tabControl"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="MultiCam">
            <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="tabControl"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Search">
            <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="tabControl"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Admin" Margin="-2,-2,-10,-1">
            <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="tabControl"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here's another trick, a `Grid` can overlap any number of elements:

```
<Grid>
    <UniformGrid Columns="4" Margin="5,0">
        <FrameworkElement x:Name="c1"/>
        <!-- no need to add the other three -->
    </UniformGrid>
    <TabControl>
        <TabItem Header="header" Width="{Binding ElementName=c1, Path=ActualWidth}"/>
        <TabItem Header="header" Width="{Binding ElementName=c1, Path=ActualWidth}"/>
        <TabItem Header="header" Width="{Binding ElementName=c1, Path=ActualWidth}"/>
        <TabItem Header="header" Width="{Binding ElementName=c1, Path=ActualWidth}"/>
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

a `UniformGrid` the same size of the `TabControl` is used to measure the width of each column. add only one `FrameworkElement` since all `TabItems` are the same size.

Comment: Technically speaking, you only need one item in your `UniformGrid` for the `ActualWidth` binding.  The grid handles the width value based upon its `Columns` property.  Additionally, you can use `FrameworkElement` rather than `Canvas`, since it's the type which actually defines the [`ActualWidth`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.actualwidth(v=vs.110).aspx) property.

Comment: @DanLyons thank you for noticing. I edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

I have a funky solution. Not sure if it's optimal. Set the width of your TabItems to the following:

```
        <TabItem Header="Search" Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType={x:Type TabControl}}, Path=ActualWidth, Converter={StaticResource quarter}}">
        </TabItem>
```

You'll need to add the converter as a static resource:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:OneQuarterConverter x:Key="quarter" />
</Window.Resources>
```

And the code for the converter is as follows:

```
class OneQuarterConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return ((double) value)/4.1;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return ((double)value) * 4.1;
    }
}
```

Divided by 4.1 because of borders and margins, etc..

Comment: Please describe `local:` in the `<Window>` Tag!